# Windows Forms, double click que abre um novo Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma tabela chamada Torneio e gostava de ao fazer DoubleClick no tipo de jogo abrisse todas as equipas desse jogo.

Tenho 4 botoes que representam os 4 jogos que tenho, nos 4 jogos tenho os torneios as equipas e as classificações e ao inserir um torneio queria que quando fizesse DoubleClick no jogo abrisse todas as equipas de cada jogo que já estão por classificação em uma datagridview.

O código é o seguinte:

```
private void Dgv1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Jogos"].Index)
            {
                EquipasLOL Tela = new EquipasLOL(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Jogos"].ToString());
                Tela.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Os Forms estão dentro da DGV?

Comment: Sim, estão todos dentro da DGV, mas não estou a conseguir fazer a ligação de ao fazer o *doubleclick* na coluna do tipo de jogo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu entendi mais ou menos mas vou fazer meu maximo.

pelo que entendi vc quer que em um dataview quando dado duplo click ele abra algo um form pelo que entendi

então vc poderia utilzar o evento de click junto com posição do mause

Codigo De Exemplo:

```
bool Click = false;
Point Cell = new Point(-1, -1);

private void Dgv1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Si possivel dezativar o multiselect antes melhor
            DataGridViewHistory.MultiSelect = false;

            // Verifica si esta na coluna certa
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != dataGridView1.Columns["Jogos"].Index) return;

            if(Click == false)
            {
                 Click = true;
                 Cell = new Point(DataGridViewHistory.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex, DataGridViewHistory.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex);
            }
            else if (Click && Cell == new Point(DataGridViewHistory.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex, DataGridViewHistory.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex))
            {
                 Click = false;
                 Tela.Show();
            }
            else if (Click == false)
            {
                 Click = true;
                 Cell = new Point(DataGridViewHistory.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex, DataGridViewHistory.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex);
            }
        }
```

Explicação eu criei um bool para poder determinar quando for o 2° click
e um point para ajudar a armazenar a colum e a row que foi selecionada e comparar si foi a mesma celula a ser clicada.

|> quando vc clica uma cellula o codigo seta o valor do point cell para o da célula selecionada.

|> quando vc da mais um click na mesma celula ele confere si e a mesma célula e si é si for o 2 click execulta ou abre o form

|> quando vc click pela 2 vez só que e em outra celula ela e seta para o ponto do 1° click para ele

Qualquer duvida só perguntar.